# How to set the direction for the vertices on mesh in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to archive the following effect:
I have an simple mesh (square). I generated it via code. Now I instantiated 4 little balls on each vertex of the square:

```
   foreach(Vector3 vert in mesh.vertices) {
        Instantiate(thing, vert, transform.rotation);
    }
```

Now I want to push this ball to every direction. It should be linear to the vertex like so:
[What I want to archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm4eA.png)

I tryed:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddRelativeForce(new Vector2(-4,1) * bulletSpeed);
```

in a new script named "ball controller" but then all the balls fly to the same direction.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddRelativeForce just applies the force in relation to the localspace of the parent object. You instead need to figure out where the `thing` is in relation to the center of the object and apply the appropriate force. For example:

```
//foreach `thing`
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddRelativeForce((thing.transform.position-transform.position).normalized * bulletSpeed);
```

Comment: This is my code now: https://pastebin.com/ZYxVY5rb It works fine but only for the both on the top, the other to vertices on the bottom pushes to the left and right

Comment: looks like it is seeing the center of your object as the bottom-middle. you either need to modify the square so that the center of the transform is in the middle, or modify the equation so that its taking the difference between the corners and the middle of the square (by adding an offset equal to half the squares height)

Comment: Yes you were right, the sqare was in one cell, the pivot is now in the exact center. https://picload.org/view/dcioiwcl/gitquestionanswer.png.html Thanks for your help!